# graphicspath and OneDrive

Tags: graphics, environments, external-files

I am trying to move my files to OneDrive and have had problem using graphicspath. I have used it successfully before but when I use it to specify a folder on OneDrive, I cannot get it to work. The specific command is

\graphicspath{ {C:\Users\jwrudn\OneDrive - Northwestern University\Data\Courses\C17\Figures } }

and the path to the file (obtained via Windows) is

"C:\Users\jwrudn\OneDrive - Northwestern University\Data\Courses\C17\Figures\Trapezoid.pdf"

Any suggestions? I am using Windows 11.

Comment: always use `/` not `\ ` in file paths, even on windows